# $p^4$ is count of ANTIsymmetric $5 \times 5$ matrices $M^2=0$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ - true?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Simulation suggests that:

$p^4$ is count of ANTIsymmetric $5\times 5$ matrices $M^2=0$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$  - is it true ?

PS

For $3\times 3$ there is only trivial solution.
For $4\times 4$ seems count = $+2p^2-1$, excluding p=2.

PSPS

Here are 16 matrices for $p=2$:

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

```
    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Doesn't $n^4$ work for all $\mathbb{Z}/n$ not just $\mathbb{F}_p$?