# Number of $F_p$-points on standard quadric $\sum x_i^2=0$ (quadratic cone) is $p^{n-1}+ (-1)^{???}(p^{n/2} - p^{n/2-1}) $, n-even?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

That should be very well-known.

Consider $\sum_{i=1...n} x_i^2=0$ over finite field $F_p$.

**(1)**
Seems number of solutions is $p^{n-1}$ for $n$ is odd i.e. $n=2k+1$.
That seems to be not difficult to explain.

**(2)**
And can be given by polynomials  for $n=2k$,
where polynomial works for all except finite set of primes:

$n = 4$, $p^3+p^2-p $ for p>2 ? (Checked for p=3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23, 29, 31)

$n = 6$, Here the answer seems to depend on p%4

$p^5+(p^3-p^2)$ for p>2 and $p\%4==1$ ? (Checked for p=5,13)

$p^5-(p^3-p^2)$ for p>2 and $p\%4 == 3$ ? (Checked for p=3,7,11)

$n = 8$, $p^7+p^4-p^3$ for p>2 ? (Checked for p=3,5,7)

So the general guess would be:

$n=2k$, Count equals to:
$$p^{n-1}+ (-1)^{sign}(p^{n/2} - p^{n/2-1}) $$

where for n=4k, sign = +1, while for n=4k+2 sign depends on p%4

**Question:** I wonder is that correct ?

---

The question has beed edited, in initial version hypothesis on "sign" was not correct.

---

Simulation code can be found here:
https://www.kaggle.com/alexandervc/count-f-q-points-on-quadric-cone-sum-x-i-2-0

Comment: A particular case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3214276) interesting for the brute force solution with Sage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of solutions of $x^2_1+\dots+x^2_n=0,$ $x_i\in \Bbb{F}_q.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183097/number-of-solutions-of-x2-1-dotsx2-n-0-x-i-in-bbbf-q)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very much for the link ! The question here is a bit more precise, and seems the n=4k+3 not covered there, but modula these details it is the same.

Comment: @JeanMarie PS and the sub-question on "bad primes" seems not be discussed there in details - that would be quite of interest for me. For n=6 prime p =5 is "bad". Are there any other examples ?

Comment: I see. It will take me some time to have a clear view of all the subcases...

Comment: Somewhat related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4254760/21498

Comment: @AlexanderChervov: Sasha, in your last formula (and in the title!) $p^n$ should be $p^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Sasha Oooops, sorry, corrected !

Comment: I believe if you work through the first 2 of Chan's lectures here: https://www.math.arizona.edu/~swc/aws/2021/index.html#2021Chan you should be able to derive a nice closed form formula for the number of points on a quadratic form over a finite field in every case.

Comment: Can you double check your calculation in the case $n=6$, $p=5$, please? [My old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/183118/11619) covers the case $p=5$, and does not show anything exceptional. I also brute forced it with Mathematica and it gave $3225=p^5+p^3-p^2$ as the answer. Anyway, Gerry Myerson's answer is also standard, from Ireland & Rosen. The answer depends on whether $p\equiv1\pmod4$ or $p\equiv-1\pmod4$. The case $p=2$ is uninteresting because Frobenius.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Salut Jyrki, thank you very much as usual for reply ! Indeed I was not quite correct about the guess on the sign. Now I have edited post and rechecked calculation. Does it agree with your answer now ?